# Positioning divs with canvas from threejs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a custom animation player. Three.js is used for render object and it works perfectly. Problem is to add something like `control` options on the bottom(like play,pause etc). I'm not sure but probably canvas is rendered as last part of page. There is my code:

```
<body>  
        <div id="playerContainer">
            <div id="renderContainer" style="width:400px;height:300px"></div>
            <div id="controlContainer" style="width:400px;height:30px">
                <input id="rangeBar" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" style="width:400px;height:30px"/>
            </div>      
        </div>      
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
            <script src="jquery.fullscreen-min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/5/Tween.js"></script>
            <script>    
                container = document.getElementById( 'renderContainer' );
                bar = document.getElementById( 'rangeBar' );
                document.body.appendChild( container ); 
                var scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, $('#renderContainer').width()/$('#renderContainer').height(), 0.1, 1000);
                camera.position.z = 5;
                camera.position.y = 0;
                camera.position.x = 0;
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( $('#renderContainer').width(), $('#renderContainer').height()-30 );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
                loader.load("model(1).json", function ( obj ) {
                    scene.add( obj );
                    render();
                    },
                    function ( xhr ) {
                        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
                    },
                    function ( xhr ) {
                        console.error( 'An error happened' );
                    }
                );
                var render = function () {
                    requestAnimationFrame(render);
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                    TWEEN.update();
                };
                render();
            </script>
    </body>
```

and the result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC85h.png)

I read something about positions in css(relative and absolute) and tried this as well:

```
<div id="playerContainer" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="renderContainer" style="width:400px;height:300px"></div>
    <div id="controlContainer" style="width:400px;height:30px">
                <input id="rangeBar" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" style="position: absolute;top:400px;width:400px;height:30px"/>
    </div>      
</div>
```

but it works worst. In both solutions `playerContainer` contains only `controlContainer` and when I set any height for that element my canvas is still at the bottom. How is it possible to get this hierarchy:

```
<PLAYER>
  <CANVAS/>
  <CONTROL/>
</PLAYER>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your css:

```
#controlContainer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

As the `controlContainer` has position absolute, and `playerContainer` is the closest relative not, the `controlContainer` should be positioned at the bottom.

Also

`position: absolute` in `rangeBar` is not necessary in this case, when positioning absolutely its container.

Hope this helps.